# SpringData mongodb crudrepository find enum value

Tags: spring, mongodb, enums

Heloo
I need to query to mongodb database and find documents with specified enum value.
here is my enum class:

```
public enum DataType {

value1,value2,value3
}
```

Here is how I implement it in repository:

```
public interface MainDataRepo extends CrudRepository<MainData, Long>{   
public Page<MainData> findTop100ByDataTypeByOrderByDateDesc(Pageable 
pageable, DataType dataType);
}
```

but this exception has been thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'mainDataRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 
by found for type DataType! Traversed path: MainData.dataType.
```

I wnoder where is the problem,
thanks.

edit:

```
This is MainData class:

@Document(collection="MainData")
public class MainData {

@Id
private Integer id;

private String text;

private String url;

private long date;

private String sender;

private String symbol;

private DataType dataType;

//setters and getters
}
```

I also change the input parameters orders, and define the method like this:

```
findTop100ByDataTypeByOrderByDateDesc(DataType dataType, Pageable pageable);
```

but still the same error.

Comment: how does your MainData class look like

Comment: Why didn't you extend your interface from `MongoRepository`? And You should give Pageable object after the query parameter(s)

Comment: @barbakini Does MongoRepository support query on enum values?

Comment: crud repository supports too.

Comment: @pvpkiran I edit ,y post and add MainData class.

Comment: @barbakini  as you suggested I place Pageable after query parameter but again the same error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name should be

```
findTop100ByDataTypeOrderByDateDesc
```

You have an extra **By** between DataType and Order. So spring data thinks there is a field named `by` and tries to search for that in you MainData class. And hence the error.